# How to sort a JSON object with sub-objects based on an attribute of its sub-objects?

Tags: json, sorting, jq

I have a list of objects that I need to index into by one of its attributes, the `name` in the below example. So I'm storing the list as an object instead of an array:

```
{
    "Foo": {
        "name": "Foo",
        "date": "2022-08-21"
    },
    "Bar": {
        "name": "Bar",
        "date": "2022-08-20"
    }
}
```

How can I sort the sub-objects by a different property of theirs (i.e. `date` in the above example), when serializing this JSON?

Answer (score 2):

By definition, the keys within a JSON object are semantically unordered, so implementations are not required to support explicit sorting of such keys in any way.

However, as of version 1.4, `jq` does preserve the order of keys within objects, and also respects the order in which they are added. So, for the problem at hand, it becomes a matter of converting the above representation into an array, sorting it, and converting it back to a JSON object:

```
jq 'to_entries | sort_by(.value.date) | from_entries'
```

---

## Explanation

First, convert the object with sub-objects into an array of `key`/`value` pairs with `to_entries`. The input becomes:

```
[
    {
        "key": "Foo",
        "value": {
            "obj1.name": "Foo",
            "obj1.date": "2022-08-21"
        }
    },
    {
        "key": "Bar",
        "value": {
            "obj2.name": "Bar",
            "obj2.date": "2022-08-20"
        }
    }
]
```

Since we now have an array, we can sort it with an arbitrary sub-object selector in `sort_by`, in my example, by `.value.date`, the output becomes:

```
[
    {
        "key": "Bar",
        "value": {
            "obj2.name": "Bar",
            "obj2.date": "2022-08-20"
        }
    },
    {
        "key": "Foo",
        "value": {
            "obj1.name": "Foo",
            "obj1.date": "2022-08-21"
        }
    }
]
```

Now it's a matter of converting the `key`/`value` form back to the object form with `from_entries`. The output becomes:

```
{
    "Bar": {
        "name": "Bar",
        "date": "2022-08-20"
    },
    "Foo": {
        "name": "Foo",
        "date": "2022-08-21"
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution also works with yq (https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/), and even gojq, though gojq gives no guarantees about the ordering of keys within objects, at least in general.